# What is the mathematically correct terminology for the contribution of each value of a set to the sum of the set?

Tags: summation, terminology, ratio

In my work I often come across situations where I would like to know how much a particular number contributes to the overall sum of the values of a set.  When referring to this value, or the set of numbers that is each individual values contribution to the sum, I  usually refer to said values as the "percentage contribution to the sum", and although this conveys the premise, I can't help but think that maybe it's not the correct label for this.  My efforts to find the correct term have fallen short repeatedly so I figured I would come to this StackExchange forum to query the math community.  Just to clarify my question I present the following situation (and I apologize in advance for this being in code as I am far more proficient in programming than mathematics formatting).

Say I have an array of 4 values

**array([16594.38194089, 16833.38403293, 28933.39527259, 28956.02268959])**

The sum of which comes to
**91317.18393599312**

resulting in a "percent composition / percent contribution  / this is the term I am looking for"  of

**array([0.18172245, 0.18433972, 0.31684502, 0.31709281])**

And that's it, that's the thing I am looking for the *correct* term for.   It's probably a really simple answer but I like to use the correct names for things whenever possible and this has been eluding me for a while.

Comment: It's possible to say, that second array is probability distribution for first.

Comment: I was thinking that as well at one point.  It is very much akin to a traditional probability distribution in terms of how it is structured, however they aren't really probabilities so much as contributors to a total.

Comment: We are able to consider such probability space, where they are exactly probabilities and then take random value on it as first array. Another general possible view is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity

Comment: Partition of Unity, the description of this sounds almost exactly like what I am trying to get at.  I dare say that's what I am looking for.

Comment: Just a note: That second array *does not* contain "percentages". (You have to multiply each by $100$ for that.) So, whatever descriptor you choose, "percent[age]" should be avoided. (Personally, I concur with "normalized values", as suggested in the answers, as dividing-out by some total value is typically called "normalization". Some care may be required to avoid confusion with, say, the normal probability distribution, or normalized geometric vectors. The dedicated statistics stack, ["Cross Validated"](https://stats.stackexchange.com), may have useful insights.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider the array as *vector* of non-negative numbers, we have a vector $x$ (in this case a $4$-tuple):
\begin{align*}
x&=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\\
&=(16594.38194089, 16833.38403293, 28933.39527259, 28956.02268959)
\end{align*}
Denoting with $\|x\|_1:=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$ its *length*, we divide each component of the vector by the length $\|x\|_1$ of it.

We obtain this way
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{x}{\|x\|_1}}&=\frac{1}{91317.18393599312}\cdot x\tag{1}\\
&=(0.18172245, 0.18433972, 0.31684502, 0.31709281)
\end{align*}
We call this vector (you might call it array) **standardised** or **normalised** by its length according to the *[L1-norm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorNorm.html)*.

*Notes:*

- The term *normalised* or *standardised* is convenient, since the components in (1) sum up to $1$.
- If elements of the vector are negative, we have to take the absolute value $\|x\|_1=|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|+|x_4|$ according to the definition of the $L1$-Norm.
- If a vector *is* already normalised, it will not be changed by an additional normalisation.  Since the sum of the components is then already $1$ and division by $1$ does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think *[proportion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proportion)* is the most correct word for what you are calculating:

> the relation of one part to another or to the whole with respect to magnitude, quantity, or degree

We also use *proportion* to mean an equality of ratios, so this might be a bit ambiguous.  One ratio would be the numbers as given $a:b:c$.  An equivalent one would be the one scaled so that the sum is one, as in $a/(a+b+c):b/(a+b+c):c/(a+b+c)$. So you could also call this expression a “normalized” ratio.

Comment: Thank you, I will likely mark this answer the correct one as it seems accurate, just going to give it a while and see what other answers are proposed.

Comment: Also, I am curious as to the proper term for the set of the proportions.  ie the proper name for the second array.